# Citation in parentheses (author outside of it)

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using the bibliographystle 'apalike' and I want to change the citation output. Given a citation

```
\cite[p.1]{citekey}
```

which til now gives "(author, year, p.1)" , I want to have something like "author (year, p.1)". This can be done by

```
\citeauthor{citekey} (\citeyear{citekey}, p.3)
```

However, there must be a better way.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about your document setup? Preferably in the form of an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). You should also revise your tags, you have added the `biblatex` tag, but from your mentioning `apalike` I don't think you actually use it. That said, if you use `natbib`, there is `\citet` maybe that can help you.

Comment: With some styles, `\citet` gives a citation of the form "Author (Year)", I don't know where exactly the postnote would go in your document and whether it actually works, but it is the best guess I have.

Comment: What about `\newcommand[2]{\citemy}{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1}, #2)}`

Comment: If you use `natbib` or `biblatex` you can indeed try and replace your `\cite[3]{foo}` by `\citet[3]{foo}`. If your bibliography setup does not support this command you will either get an error, a warning or weird output. We can only really make sure that a command works for you if we know exactly what your setup looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{citekey,
    address = {Nowhere land},
    author = {Nowhere Man},
    publisher = {University of Void Press},
    title = {On the Nothing of Nothingness},
    year = {9999}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newif\ifnatbib
\natbibtrue

\documentclass{article}

\ifnatbib
  \usepackage{natbib}
\else
  \usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\fi

\makeatletter
\providecommand\citet[2][]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}
  \citeauthor{#2} (%
    \citeyear{#2}%
    \ifx\@empty\@tempa\else,~#1\fi
  )
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
As first example citation here is \cite[p.1]{citekey}. 
Here is another example citation \citet[p.1]{citekey}.

\ifnatbib
  \bibliographystyle{apalike}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\else
  \printbibliography
\fi
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]

Answer (score 2):

As Moewe commented:

```
\citet[p.1]{citekey}
```